# Variance of integer-valued random variable equal to sum of variances of characteristic functions

Tags: probability-theory

Here is the claim I'm trying to understand: Given that $N$ is an integer-valued random variable, why is it true that

$$Var(N) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty Var(1_{N\ge i})$$

For context, this is a step in the answer to exercise 4.5.10 in Rosenthal, *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory*, 2nd ed., p. 53, which I'm trying to work through in self-study.

If one were to substitute expectation for variance, then proposition 4.2.9 would apply, which shows that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X \ge k) = E\lfloor X \rfloor$. And we no longer need the floor function if $X$ is integer valued. Variance is of course defined as an expectation, but even if the original random variable ($N$ above) is integer-valued, its mean doesn't have to be, and that means that the random variable $(N - E(N))^2$ isn't necessarily integer valued, so that theorem doesn't apply directly.

Is there another way to see why the above claim is true?

Comment: You can get the proper font for $\operatorname{Var}$ using `\operatorname{Var}`.

Comment: You have posted something different from what the exercise says.  In ex. 4.5.10 they compute $Var(S)$ and not Var(N). They reach the correct result.

Comment: @Jimmy They don't state the result, so I'm not sure what you mean. The problem is to compute $Var(S)$ in terms of other supposedly known parameters, one of which is $Var(N)$. The solution cited below by joriki uses the claim I mention. I'm still digesting joriki's argument that the "solution" is wrong--i.e., making a complete counter-example.

Comment: @MarshallFarrier: For a complete counter-example you can consider $N$ with support on $\{1,2,3\}$. The difference between the two sides in this case is $p_1p_3$.

Comment: @joriki I was hesitating to use that because of getting infinitely many independent random variables. But I supposed you could just set $X_i = 1$ for all $i$, and they're all independent with expectation 1 and variance 0.

Comment: @MarshallFarrier: Yes, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: @MarshallFarrier I meant that they prove the correct result: $Var(S)=σ^2μ+m^2ν$ (using their notation). The proof may use something that does not hold, but they reach a result that holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong. We have $N=\sum_i1_{N\ge i}$, so the equation would hold if the indicator variables were all independent. But they're not; they're all positively correlated, so we need to add their positive covariances.

[Here's a solution manual](http://math.uh.edu/%7Ejosic/myweb/teaching/probability/A%20Collection%20of%20Exercises%20in%20Avdanced%20Prob%20Theory.pdf) that claims to solve this exercise on p. $17$. The error is in the step where they replace $E(1_{N\ge i}1_{N\ge j})$ by $E(1_{N\ge i})E(1_{N\ge j})$ in the second term of $E(S^2)$, thus ignoring the correlation between the two indicator variables.

An easy case to see this clearly is $j=i+1$ and $P(N=i)=0$; then $1_{N\ge i}=1_{N\ge j}$ with complete correlation.

Comment: Using $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}, N(1)=1, N(2)=3, N(3)=5$ I get $Var(N)=8/3$ but $\sum_{i=1}^\infty Var(1_{N \ge i}) = 8/9$. So, you are right. This doesn't hold. Now to figure out the *right* answer to the original problem! :)

Comment: @MarshallFarrier: I wouldn't be surprised if the right answer is the answer they got in the solution manual, since it makes a lot of sense and the two errors they made (the one in the step you were looking at and the one I pointed out in the answer) might cancel.

Comment: agreed. I can't get it to work with the theorems available, though, after working with it for a good while. I think I'm just going to move on.

Comment: @MarshallFarrier: I wrote to the authors of the solution manual to point out the error, and one of them responded with an alternative solution of Exercise $4.5.10$, using Theorem $13.3.1$ in the book with $Y=S$ and $X=N$. Of course Chapter $13$ comes after Chapter $4$...

Answer (score 0):

@ MarshalFarrier, @Jimmy, @ Joriki:

The corrected solution (including correlation) and an additional solution has been posted here:

http://probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/Ex4.5.10sol.pdf